# Exit from application in android

Tags: android

I have to exit from application when user is some in middle of application. I have use finish() and System.exit(0) method but it only exits current activity.
If any one know about this please let me know.

Thank You

Vikram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are calling activity B from an activity A.and C from B

A->B

use startactivityforresult from A

and again B->C

use startactivityforresult from B

and when you want to exit from C then setResult(i.e. RESULT_OK) and finish C.and in OnActivityResult() in B,check if resultcode == RESULT_OK then again finish B and setresult(RESULT_OK) for A.same procedure will follow to finish A.

this will exit you from the application.and application will start from A not from C.

Answer (score 0):

try this (*Not tested):

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        this.finish();
    }
```

Also try to Spare some time to go through [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)